# Jsonc not working on IE?

Tags: json, jquery, youtube-api

The following code - a youtube loader with thumbnails - works in FF and Chrome, but not in IE. I am wondering if it's about the Jsonc call. I've heard it is better to use Jsonp with IE. Nonetheless I'd like to use Jsonc for my project. Could please someone enlighten me about this issue? I am stuck...

```
<script>
var player;

$(document).ready(function(){

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        player = new YT.Player('video', {
            events: {
                'onReady': function () {
                     $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/diasporaduo/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc", function (json) {
                         videoid = json.data.items[0].id;
                            player.cueVideoById(videoid);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is make a CORS call, and that's not supported in Internet Explorer versions earlier than 10: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/05/unlocking-javascripts-potential-with.html

You should use JSONP if you care about compatibility with older versions of IE. jQuery makes that pretty easy with its `$.ajax()` method.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. I solved it using a workaround:  swfobject.embedSWF. However, I could not embed the code in my $(document).ready(function()[]).